# Export sheets top pdf bases on cell values

Tags: excel, vba, export

I am trying to export different sets of sheets to specified maps as pdf format.
The workbook contains multiple sheets and in the sheet Printlist i have a list of the specified sheets, filenames and maps. (see image)

I want to write a macro that prints te sheetnames with the filenames to the specified maps but my current macro does not do the trick
[image: ![sheet]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9NQU.jpg) 
Code:

```
Sub PDF_maken()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim Mypath As String

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Printlijst")
LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each r In ws.Range("B2:B" & LR)

If Not IsEmty("B" & r) Then
Mypath = ws.Range("B" & r).Text
Sheets(Array(ws.Range("D" & r).Text, ws.Range("E" & r).Text, ws.Range("F" & r).Text, ws.Range("G" & r).Text)).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
Mypath & ws.Range("C" & r).Text & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End If

Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: There are a fair number of errors in the code, including syntax ones which will prevent it from running anyway (IsEmty instead of IsEmpty for example).  I presume that's only an issue in the post rather than the code - can you confirm what the problem you are seeing is and where in the code it happens?

Comment: The first error occurs at the line     Mypath - ws.Range("B"& r).Text. When i view r it says r is the value from the cell, I think r should be the row number.

Comment: Try changing the loop to `For r = 2 to LR` ; currently you're setting r to be parts of a range object

Comment: Change references to `r` within the loop to `r.Row`

Comment: Yes this works, I used Jordans Method. Now the exporting stops in when trying to select the blank cell (G2). Since not everybody has the same amount of sheets the array of sheets must be made dynamic. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been a while but if someone has the same problem here is the code that fixed it:

```
Sub PDF_maken()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim Mypath As String
Dim strarray As String
Dim Test As String
Dim strItem As String

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Printlijst")
LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

For Each r In ws.Range("D3:D" & LR).Cells

strItem = ws.Range("E" & r.Row).Text
strItem = Replace(strItem, "~", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, Chr(34), "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, "%", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, "#", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, "&", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, "*", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, ":", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, ",", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, "<", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, ">", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, "?", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, "{", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, "}", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, "|", "_")
strItem = Replace(strItem, "/", "_")

If Not IsEmpty("D" & r.Row) Then
Mypath = ws.Range("D" & r.Row).Text
strarray = ""
colCheck = 6
Do Until Cells(r.Row, colCheck) = ""
strarray = strarray & IIf(colCheck > 6, ",", "") & Cells(r.Row, colCheck).Value
colCheck = colCheck + 1
Loop


If InStr(1, strarray, ",") Then
Dim MyAr As Variant
    MyAr = Split(strarray, ",") '<~~ This is where we are creating an actual array


        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(MyAr).Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Range("F" & r.Row).Text).Activate
    
   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
Mypath & strItem & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False


Else
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(strarray).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
Mypath & strItem & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End If
 End If
ws.Activate

Next r

   End Sub
```